# Don't start virtual device automatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I usually want to test my apps on a real phone but I still have a virtual device to test the latest stuff not supported by the test phone. My problem is that after plugging in the phone into the USB port it asks for a confirmation to allow access, which I usually forget and so android studio starts the virtual device. Very annoying! Android Studio used to have a run popup where it asked which device to run the app on, but it no longer shows the popup in any of my projects. Can this popup be re-enabled? Or what else can I do (except to delete the virtual device)?

Answer (score 1):

Next to the Run icon in the top toolbar, right, there is a dropdown list where you can select the Run Configuration.  Typically it is pointed to 'app'.  If you open the drop-down, there is a choice to Edit Configurations.  For both Release and Debug, you should look at Deployment target Options:, Target: and select 'Open Select Deployment Target Dialog', and do not check 'Use same device for future launches'.  Then click Apply, and OK.

Comment: I don't have these options. I have the "Edit Configurations..." option in the dropdown, which opens a window titled: "Run/Debug Configurations" but that doesn't contain the options you are talking about. I think I remember these options but they were removed. What is your Android Studio version? Mine is 3.5.2

Comment: I have 3.4.2 but it should be the same in yours.  When you open the Edit Configurations dialog, you need to be sure to select your run configuration in the list on the left.  If you select Templates, you won't see anything, but if you select your run configuration (usually 'app' under Android App) you will see some tabs, General, Miscellaneous, Debugger and Profiling.  You want to select General, then scroll down to Deployment Target Options.

Comment: I am there, in the General tab, but all I have is: Module: dropdown box, Installation  Options (Deploy: Default APK, Install Flags), Launch Options (Launch: Default Activity, Launch flags) and Before Launch with options like Gradle-aware Make but no deployment target anywhere. Actually that Before Launch is there for all the tabs (misc, debugger, profiling).

Comment: Crap, I just found this: https://superuser.com/questions/1477698/deployment-target-options-absent-in-android-studio

Comment: Yea, I read about that new feature in 3.5 and wondered if it was related to your problem.  Any way for you to roll back to version 3.4?

Comment: I suppose that would be difficult because my preferences have been converted to 3.5 format and the old dir was deleted during update (I don't know how backward compatible that directory is). I filed a report using the frown face icon in the toolbar, hopefully google will react, here it is if you're interested: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144249612

Comment: I am interested.  Think I'll hold off updating for a while, as I agree, the way it works in the older version is the ideal solution.